# LibGDX different assets for different resolutions like Android

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

I have a game developed natively for Android, and now my users also want an iOS version. I thought LibGDX would be the better choice because it'll let me reuse Java code from the game, and also I already have some experience with it.

In my game I have different image sizes for different device densities (in drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi and so on).

So, my question is: how can I achieve the same, but using LibGDX (also taking care of the new densities required by iOS device resolutions, if any change is required)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve the same, but it wont be automatic like on Android unless you write some native code as well. I have found that the best way to manage it is simply to do it yourself:

1) When your app starts you can get the [screen size](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html) and density using `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()`, `getWidth()`, `Gdx.graphics.getDensity()`

2) Depending on the size and density you can change the location path to the correct folder where your assets should be loaded from.

3) Now when any asset loading code is run make sure that it uses your pre-set path from the step above, so that you get the correct assets for that display size/density.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you can use the largest image and use [`Viewports'](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) to handle resolution and aspect ratio for you. The larger images will be scaled down and this will result in some loss of detail of course.

Viewports will automatically scale the size you want to show of your game world to the screen it displays it. For example `FitViewport(100, 100)` will create a viewport that shows `100 x 100` "game units". If you would play this on a `1920 x 1080` device it will scale that `100 x 100` game world to a `1080 x 1080` area and leave an empty bar of `840 x 1080`.

The size of the game world has nothing to do with pixels. You could create a enemy with the size of `0.5f x 0.5f` world units and give that a texture of `256 x 256` pixels. Your viewport scales this for you to the correct size.

Unless you want a pixel perfect game this should be good enough. On some bigger screens but low resolutions devices you might get some minor artefacts due to filtering, setting the filtering for your textures `Texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Linear)` might fix some.

All I ever think about when designing graphics are the pixels in my art should represent roughly or at least 1 screen pixel. Usually I just draw pixel perfect for HD and it looks fine on a `800 x 480` screen. If you want to squeeze out a bit more performance you could use `MipMaps`, I think `TexturePacker` generates them automatically with the right `Filter` settings but I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using

```
com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.resolvers.ResolutionFileResolver.
```

Here is [javadoc](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/resolvers/ResolutionFileResolver.html) for it.